# JavaScript: Make first hidden element visible

Tags: javascript

How can I find the first element in a document which has style="display:none;" set and make it visible?

I want to attach this function to a button to display several hidden elements, one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple Javascript:

```
var el=document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for(i=0;i<el.length;i++)
   if(el[i].style.display=="none"){
       el[i].style.display="block";
       break;
   }
```

Comment: Yes this is correct but more better to use "" instead of the "block" to display elements. As with the block type some times elements starts moving around the screen and makes life difficult. :)

Answer (score 3):

In jQuery it's simple:

```
$(':hidden:first').show();
```

but if you haven't got access to jQuery, it's a bit more complicated. Any information about what elements might possibly be hidden would be helpful to come up with a good resolution to this in plain javascript. Are they all children of a certain DIV? Are they all of a certain element?